# DimensionValuesLookup on my own EDT

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r3, aot

I need to create an **EDT** that will use **DimnesionValuesLookup**.

So I've made an EDT with reference to my View that has DisplayValues for my specific dimension type, also I set **formHelp** property as **DimnesionValuesLookup**. And when I'm trying to open lookup on query search criteria I get an error:

> Form should be called with parameters

I looked into the *Init()* method of **DimnesionValuesLookup** and found out that I need to pass **DimensionAttribute** as a record.

How can I do this?

Comment: The `DimensionAttribute` record determines what dimension will be used to display values in the lookup. How do you decide what dimension you want to use?

Comment: @FH-Inway I have a view for my specific dimension type, so basically I have RecId + DisplayValue in view. Then I join it to the main query.

Answer (score -1):

Your comment did not answer my question, but I'm assuming you have a way to identify the name of the attribute for which you want to lookup values. Using the name you can select the `DimensionAttribute` record that you need to call the lookup form by using the `findByName` method of table `DimensionAttribute`. After that you can call the lookup form. Standard AX does something very similar in form `DimensionValueInterval`, take a look at the `lookup` method there.

Comment: "call the lookup form" - so how can I do that? Don't forget that we are talking about query search criteria form.